# Redis CLUSTER NODES showing in slowlog

Tags: redis

I am using a redis cluster with 3 master and 3 slave as mysql cache,and the client is redisson with @Cacheabel annotation.But I found some slow logs with the command CLUSTER NODES like:

`3) 1) (integer) 4
   2) (integer) 1573033128
   3) (integer) 10955
   4) 1) "CLUSTER"
      2) "NODES"
   5) "192.168.110.102:57172"
   6) ""
4) 1) (integer) 3
   2) (integer) 1573032928
   3) (integer) 10120
   4) 1) "CLUSTER"
      2) "NODES"
   5) "192.168.110.90:59456"
   6) ""`

So ,I want to know what was the problem?

Comment: I also see the same problem but in my case. I see the following commands in the slow logs "CLUSTER NODES", "INFO", "INFO ALL", "PING" etc. Are you seeing this problem in the AWS Elasticache (redis) service?. I am guessing this could be an AWS bug.